# Codeigniter not CHMOD 777 directory

Tags: codeigniter, chmod

I can't find why does my Codeigniter not CHMOD specific directory to 777 from the controller, so looking for some advice on how to solve this.

I'm running centos 7, PHP 7.2

I have a controller with a location: public_html/application/controllers/users.php
And I need to CHMOD directory: public_html/uploads/whatverfolder/userfolder/

```
public function att() {
$uploaddir = 'uploads/whatverfolder/userfolder';
if (file_exists($uploaddir )) {
echo 'YES DIRECTORY EXIST'; // geting success
@chmod($uploaddir, FILE_WRITE_MODE); // -> not working
chmod($uploaddir, 0777, true); // -> not working
}
}
```

This is error I'm getting:

```
ERROR - 11th July 2019 10:10:24 --> Severity: Warning  --> chmod(): Can not call chmod() for a non-standard stream /home/u7658/web/mydomain.com/public_html/application/controllers/users.php 1578
ERROR - 11th July 2019 10:10:24 --> Severity: Warning  --> chmod(): Operation not permitted /home/u7658/web/mydomain.com/public_html/application/controllers/users.php 1585
```

Also, ownership of the folder to chmod is a root [0] (that's correct)
Also, that folder has been created by CodeIgniter, by this code (directory has been created but with 775 permission, even when mkdir should create a directory with 777 permission.

```
$domainpath = "./uploads/domeny/".$ID."/";

// make folder
    if (!file_exists($domainpath)) {
    mkdir($domainpath, 0777, true);
}
```

I just missing something, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use `BASEPATH`from config to achive absolute path

```
$folderPath = '';//here you need to give absolute path i.e C:\wamp\www\project_folder/uploads/domeny/
mkdir("$folderPath");
chmod("$folderPath", 0777);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that this specific directory has not been created by mkdir, that directory (due to migration) has been upload by FTP.
So, I dont know why but If you upload on my server directory by FTP, then you are not allowed to chmod that directory by php, probably due to OWNER/GROUP perm.
But my perm for that folder was root.. so still not sure why, but It's working now.